# C# reading PDF with ASCII chars

Tags: c#, pdf, ascii

I am reading a PDF file with the iText library version 4.1.6 and usually everything works fine. Now when I read PDFs which are created by a PDF print driver (with print functionallity over MS Word) I get some ASCII chars and cant convert them correctly. Some of the PDF signs are converted correctly like the tokens BT (Begin Text), ET (End Text) etc. But when it comes to text objects which are stored in a PDF array (from the PDF ISO, not in my C# code!) the single chars have strange values. E.g. I have a 'R', but in bytes it has the value '1'. In the ASCII table a R is '82' (dec). So I get values like 'SOH' for this char. Other libraries can somehow convert this. Can someone please tell me how can I convert this single byte to it's letter 'R'? I searched for hours and nothing works till now.

Here is the recent code how I read PDF files (iText v. 4.1.6)

```
public string ExtractPureText(string filename)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Create a reader for the given PDF file
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);

        int totalLen = 68;
        float charUnit = ((float)totalLen) / (float)reader.NumberOfPages;

        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(ExtractPureTextFromPDFBytes(reader.GetPageContent(page), page) + " ");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Here is the ExtractPureTextFromPDFBytes function

```
public string ExtractPureTextFromPDFBytes(byte[] input, int pageNumber)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length == 0) return "";

        int readPosition = 0;
        Encoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding(true, false);

        try
        {
            string resultString = "";

            // Flag showing if we are we currently inside a text object
            bool inTextObject = false;

            // Flag showing if the next character is literal 
            // e.g. '\\' to get a '\' character or '\(' to get '('
            bool nextLiteral = false;

            // () Bracket nesting level. Text appears inside ()
            int bracketDepth = 0;

            // Keep previous chars to get extract numbers etc.:
            char[] previousCharacters = new char[_numberOfCharsToKeep];
            for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfCharsToKeep; j++) previousCharacters[j] = ' ';


            for (readPosition = 0; readPosition < input.Length; readPosition++)
            {
                char c = (char)input[readPosition];
                if (input[readPosition] == 213)
                    c = "'".ToCharArray()[0];


                if (inTextObject)
                {
                    byte[] b = new byte[2];
                    b[0] = 0;
                    b[1] = input[116];

                    byte[] d = new byte[1];
                    d[0] = input[116];
                    string bString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);

                    if (readPosition >= 114)
                    {
                        String t = new String((char)(input[116] & 0xff), 1);
                    }
                    // Position the text
                    if (bracketDepth == 0)
                    {
                        if (CheckToken(new string[] { "TD", "Td", "'", "T*", "\"", "TJ", "Tj", "Tf" }, previousCharacters))
                        {
                            resultString += System.Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                    }

                    // End of a text object, also go to a new line.
                    if (bracketDepth == 0 && CheckToken(new string[] { "ET" }, previousCharacters))
                    {
                        resultString += System.Environment.NewLine;
                        inTextObject = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Start outputting text
                        if ((c == '(') && (bracketDepth == 0) && (!nextLiteral))
                        {
                            bracketDepth = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Stop outputting text
                            if ((c == ')') && (bracketDepth == 1) && (!nextLiteral))
                            {
                                bracketDepth = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Just a normal text character:
                                if (bracketDepth == 1)
                                {
                                    // Only print out next character no matter what. 
                                    // Do not interpret.
                                    if (c == '\\' && !nextLiteral)
                                    {
                                        //resultString += c.ToString();
                                        nextLiteral = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (((c >= ' ') && (c <= '~')) ||
                                            ((c >= 128) && (c < 255)))
                                        {
                                            //resultString += c.ToString();
                                        }

                                        nextLiteral = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                resultString += c.ToString();

                // Store the recent characters for 
                // when we have to go back for a checking
                for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfCharsToKeep - 1; j++)
                {
                    previousCharacters[j] = previousCharacters[j + 1];
                }
                previousCharacters[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] = c;

                // Start of a text object
                if (!inTextObject && CheckToken(new string[] { "BT" }, previousCharacters))
                {
                    inTextObject = true;
                    resultString += System.Environment.NewLine;
                    resultString += pageNumber.ToString() + " PN" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }

            string output = string.Empty;

            // clean up text, remove empty lines and trim lines
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(resultString))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Trim();
                    if (line != string.Empty)
                    {
                        output += line + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

It is for me absolutely no option to get the higher version of iText because of lincensing. Only if there would be a library which has a developer license, but iText license have to be paid for every machine my own software will be installed. Unfortunately this is no option for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show any of the code around this? i.e. how are you getting this "value '1'"?

Comment: The font parsing part of text extraction in iText(Sharp) has been considerably improved during the 5.x version history. iText(Sharp) text parsing in the 4.x version was at the state of a prove of concept. That being said, how do you extract the text? Are you using the parser namespace at all?